# Function template to return pointer to specified subclass

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I want to create a templated function that can create and initialize a new instance of any class that is a subclass of Actor, and return a pointer of the subclass type. I am still trying to figure out the finer points of templates in C++, so maybe I am going about this in completely the wrong way.

I have my project set up something like this - A base class, Actor, sub classes, and an ActorFactory with the static method "spawn".

```
class Actor {
public:
    Actor();
    ~Actor();

    int attributeA;
    int attributeB;
    Vector3 location;
    Rotator rotation;
}

class SubA : public Actor {
public:
    SubA() {
        attributeA = 1;
        attributeB = 2;
    }
    ~SubA();
}

class SubB : public Actor {
public:
    SubB() {
        attributeA = 3;
        attributeB = 4;
    }
    ~SubB();
}

class ActorFactory {
public:
    ActorFactory();
    ~ActorFactory();

    template <class T>
    static T *spawn(Vector3 loc, Rotator rot) {
        T *actor = new T();

        actor->location = loc;
        actor->rotation = rot;

        return actor;
    }
}
```

Then I would like to be able to make a simple call like this, elsewhere in my code:

```
SubA *a = ActorFactory::spawn<SubA>(aVector, aRotator);
```

Currently I am getting an unresolved external symbol when trying to call spawn(). Also, I'm not sure if there is a way to better restrict the inputs on the spawn function, other than creating the new instance, then attempting a dynamic_cast to make sure it is a derivative of Actor, before proceeding. Is there some way to accomplish what I am going for, or should I just implement a basic factory method that return an Actor pointer every time, and work from there?

Comment: Have you implemented all of the member functions declared in the code you’ve shown? Which symbol is unresolved? That would be the first place to look.

Comment: @JonPurdy Yes, all of the member functions are declared in headers, and defined in cpp files. The unresolved external symbol is on the line where I call "ActorFactory::spawn<SubA>(aVector, aRotator)". It compiles and runs fine with a simpler spawn function, which takes the same arguments, but doesn't use templates, and always returns a pointer of type Actor - which is annoying to work with.

Comment: @Devon You need to move the *definition* of the templated `spawn` function to the header file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Comment: @DanielFrey Thanks, that was indeed the issue. I figured it was some simple error like that... Oddly in all of my research, reading about templates today, I didn't come across a single comment about templates needing to be in headers.

Comment: For the base-check, you don't need `dynamic_cast`, you can just use implicit conversions for the upcast, like `Base* p = maybe_derived_ptr;`. However, one can still do better than that - take a look at `static_assert` and `is_base_of` from either C++11 or Boost.